# Cursor gets stuck in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, cursor

In my drag-and-drop implementation, I create a "mask" element over the whole page and apply a `mousemove` event to it, along with a CSS `cursor` property as needed and relevant. The mask element is then removed when the element being dragged is dropped. This works perfectly fine, however in IE the cursor gets temporarily stuck. It stays at whatever the mask had it set to, but reverts to normal when anything is done (clicking anywhere, pressing any key on the keyboard, but NOT just moving the mouse). This isn't a major problem, but it can be confusing - especially in the case where the element being dragged is small so I set the cursor to `none` in order to make it easier to see what is being done.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I made a test page and it's working just fine, so it's probably because of how complex the page is. Interestingly, the cursor doesn't just get stuck in the document, it gets stuck elsewhere on the window too - I have to unstick it to be able to change tabs or type in the URL bar, for example. It seems like the JavaScript is affecting the entire program, which seems more like an IE bug than a JavaScript error...

Comment: Can you throw a simple example into jsFiddle so we can reproduce this?

Comment: I would, but I don't think a "simple example" would cut it. I'll see if I can make a proper test to reproduce the issue, but since it's quite a complex page it might not be so easy to make a test page. Will update when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I did, but it's fixed now. Possibly something small like making the mask scrollable (in case the mask's content is bigger than the page) is all it took.